# Unique Validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can I create users with same email address but for different location using unique validation rules?

How can I do it in a code like this,

```
return [
    'name'=>'required',
    'email'=>'required|email',
    'location'=>'required',
    'password'=>'required|confirmed'
];
```

Comment: remove unique constraint from email field in users table and then try this `'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('location', $request->location);
})`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,NULL,id,location,'.$this->location
```

and in database users table remove email unique constraint and add below code

```
$table->unique(['email', 'location']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change column of user table email column to not unique, You need to change the structure of database table user because default migration for users in laravel contain unique constraints for email.